# Checking if a given boolean array can match a target boolean array after performing a set of actions

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

This task was actually given to us as homework, but the requirement in the homework assignment was to write a recursive method that can return true or false if array A can match array B after we perform a few steps on array A, I've already answered this question in a recursive manner, and i am interested in finding if there is a more intelligent approach to it, a certain pattern or equation that can be used to address this type of assignment,
that being said, i am not sure if the homework tag is still relevant, but i added it just in case.

Here are the details:
Given two boolean arrays, identical in length. return true if a given array "init" can match target array "target",
The catch is: whenever we "flip" the value of one index from true to false and vice-versa, the values in the indexes to the right and left of the current index, flip their value as well (if such an index is within the array bounds of course), for example:

```
boolean[] init =   {true, false, true, false, true, false};
boolean[] target = {false, true, false, true, false, true};
```

in this case the answer is true, as we can flip the first spot [0] of init array, resulting in:

```
boolean[] init =   {false, true, false, false, true, false);
boolean[] target = {false, true, false, true, false, true};
```

and then flip the 4th spot [3] in init array, resulting in a match between the init and target arrays:

```
boolean[] init =   {false, true, false, true, false, true};
boolean[] target = {false, true, false, true, false, true};
```

recursively it was just testing the two options of a "flipped state" or without a "flipped state" and advancing in the array's index for each test, which will recursively check all the options, eventually returning true if a match is found.

Now focusing back on my question, is there a better approach to this kind of problem without having to check so many options? it doesn't have to be recursive... as a matter of fact, it may be best if it wasn't :)
so please feel free to share your ideas and suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just try and solve the problem yourself?  Yes, I know it isn't homework, but you can learn from other things than homework.

Comment: @StephenC I have a bit of a problem with just throwing guesses into something and see what works, to begin with i am new to java and rather inexperienced, but i find it more productive for me at least to think of an approach and plan an idea, and only then write it and see how it goes, i could be wrong (again, too inexperienced to say), but i frankly cant think of something that wont go in the same pattern of a recursive method, even if used in a loop, that is why i present this question to get more ideas and hopefully improve my view on approaching such problems.

Comment: This can be answered in linear time. Here is a hint, if you don't care about the last value in the array, you can easily guarantee every other value matches.

Comment: Looking at this problem from a higher level, you can remodel this as a graph traversal problem.

Comment: @DarcyRayner: I'm not sure about linear time. Can you demonstrate with this case: `0110` --> `0000`?

Comment: @DarcyRayner I tried looking for some pattern which can be used, but it answers only specific cases, for example, if the first value of the init array equals to the next index in the target array and so on (a "zipper" arrangement) you can easily say that init can reach the target array, but this is obviously not the case for other scenarios, remember that array init and array target can be a lot longer and contain any random set of value arrangement between true and false, this example above is just very convenient, but it is not expected to be the case all the time.

Comment: You mean spot[1] and spot[4] I assume? Are you looking for code to produce yes/no - or to produce the transformation?

Comment: @esej just a yes\no confirmation, i just want to know if it *can* be reached, not how it is reached, this is why i think it may be possible to utilize a more effective \ "smart trick" to get it done, but i could be wrong...

Comment: You also need to answer my first question, or to be more specific - can I flip just the first two - or is the "first" legal flip the first three?

Comment: @esej I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, but if it clarifies: you can flip any switch at any order and perform as many actions as you need to confirm or deny that init can match target eventually, this is of course considering you follow the limitations of having the two adjacent right and left cells flip their value as well, for example if i have 0000 and i would flip the 1st number it would be 1100 if i would then flip the 3rd number it would be: 1011, hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes it does, I read your question then as you don't flip the first (as you wrote) but the second cell in your first flip.

Comment: Thank you everyone for all your assistance and effort! it is much appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to speed up the implementation (of answering yes/no to the question whether we can transform the array with the given rule):

- Represent everything as bits instead of array of true and false value. Then the bit flipping patterns are: 1100...00, 1110...00, 0111...00, ..., 0000...11. We will search all the possible ways that the bit flipping pattern can transform an array by doing a BFS (or DFS).
- Store whether a transformation is possible with bit set (if the language allows such low level implementation or provided with such library) or array of char/boolean. This will reduce the space used by the transformation. The size of the array/bit set is 2 ^ n.
- When you have obtained all the possible transformation, you can answer the question with a fixed number of elements in O(1) by XORing the input and the target, then check whether such transformation exists. Well, if the number of elements varies, then there is not much advantage.

It should be able go up to 20-23 bits while still keep the time under 1-3 seconds (assuming C++ code). For Java, it is probably a tad bit slower, but should be under 30 seconds.

The time complexity is no better than your current method, though.

You can also search for the transformation pattern 0000...01 (terminate early, instead of searching for the whole space of possible transformation), then use the method that Darcy Rayner suggested. The worst case complexity is no better than your current method.

<s>I don't know if there is any mathematical solution to this problem. Currently, this is all brute force.</s>

**EDIT**

Mathematically, it is possible to prove that we can greedily reduce the difference to at most 1 with the method that Darcy Rayner suggested (by analyzing at the last 2 bits).

It also can be proven that we can negate the whole pattern any time, i.e. for length 3k, trivial, for length 3k + 1, flip at the both ends, and all groups of 3 in the middle, for length 3k + 2, flip at one end, and all groups of 3 in the middle.

So if we have the last bit = 1, we can flip the whole pattern. If the original length is 3k + 1, we end up with 3k differences (true), which can be flipped trivially. If the original length is 3k, we end up with 3k - 1 differences, which we can flip at one end, and flip every group of 3. In those 2 cases (length 3k + 1 and length 3k), transformation is always possible.

I currently has no disproof for the case 3k + 2.

Comment: Cheers! it does start to make sense, checking this route now as well

Comment: Note: I expect 3k + 2 cases to be generally split into 2 distinct sets of mutually transformable patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not going to write an implementation, but here is the basic logic. Figure out which values need to change, eg. {true ,false ,false,true} with { true, true,false,false} = {true != true,false != true, false != false, true != false} = {false,true,false,true}

Now, we are going to try to flip this new array until all the values from 0 to (size-2) are equal to false. We know we can do this linearly. if a[0] == true, flip at a[1], if a[1] == true, flip at a[2]. Just step through each value, to size - 2.

Eventually the entire array will be false, except the last value which will either be true or false. Now the question is, if only the last value is true, is it possible to transform the array so that all values are false?

Comment: Partial solution... Since in case of 4 or 6 bits, you can, but in case of 5 bits, you cannot.

Comment: Does the length of the array matter, other than whether it is odd or even length?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i am trying to look more into what you suggested right now, i also sort of found just now (at least on 5 attempts I've made) that as long as init and target have an equal amount of 1s (true) and 0s (false), a match can be reached, again, this is based on 5 different tests I've just made, can someone else prove or deny this assumption? i am looking into this assumption further as well, i want to see if we can conclude an answer of true or false based on a set of fixed boolean facts we can ask, at best after doing a linear loop on the arrays

Comment: @DarcyRayner: It's not about odd or even. I only confirmed that any patterns are transformable if the length if 4 or 6, but there are 2 partition in case of length 5.

Comment: sorry, disregard my last comment, i just concluded after navigating the stupidity of morning brain that the number or true \ false can easily be altered... duh. so this cant be a correct assumption, ill keep looking into your approach

Comment: Think really carefully about the case of 5, can it be converted to all false if the last value is true? What about 7, or 9, or 11? There is a very simple pattern.

Comment: @DarcyRayner, I didn't manage to convert all false if the last value is true in a length 5 array, but for 7 i did manage to make all false, i need to re-check to make sure i didn't make any mistake in my manual pen and paper conversions, or it is part of your point and i still just miss the obvious pattern here, we'll get there :)

Comment: 0000001 -> 1100001 -> 0010001 -> 0001101 -> 0000011 -> 0000000

Comment: @DarcyRayner but your last result is of length 4 and not 5, i am not sure i follow you here
Edit:
but how did you get from 00101 -> 00000
sorry if its a case of morning stupidity, when you sink into something too much you lose your focus :(

Comment: @DarcyRayner: Wrong. I confirmed by hand length 5 has 2 partitions of mutually transformable pattern.

Comment: @DarcyRayner
sorry mate i still cant see how you got from 00101 to 00000
what am i missing here? :S

Edit:
oh i see now, i was confused about the case of 5 and 7 being the same while 5 didn't work for me

Comment: Wait, I screwed up with the case of 5, there is no solution for that if the final value is true. I think it might be a special case though.

Answer (score 1):

***Commentary***

For n bits, there can be n operations for different changes.

- The **order** of operations is **irrelevant**! (commutative, associative)
- Doing an operation **twice** restores the **same** state. (reflective)

Hence every solution is a subset of n operations, to be executed in whatever order.

- *Not relevant for an algorithm:* If there are k > 4 consecutive unchanged bits, the operations with middle bit at [i+2] to [k-1-2] can be excluded.
- **At most 3 operations influence a specific bit**. So for all different bits you can collect which operations to select from.
- Of those 3 operations for one bit **1 or 3 operations** have to be elected (2 operations would restore it).

Comment: Nice observations, even if it isn't an answer.